# Openpyxl How does one define print area from a variable or other input like max rows?

Tags: openpyxl

I am very new to python in general but have a set of code where I am needing to define the print area for multiple excel files. My code is built to step through thousands of files in a directory and they are all relatively similar but vary in row length.

I am trying to do something akin to:

`worksheet.print_area = "['A1' : 'F' + str(max_rows)]"`

The code above is not working because it is not a valid coordinate range because I am guessing the print.area function is requiring an exact range like [A1:F45].  But I am needing that last number to be able to change depending on the max rows within the sheet.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: You are including your variable inside the string. To create as a string concatenation you just need **worksheet.print_area = "A1:F" + str(max_rows)**, **str(max_rows)** is appended to the string as a variable [not in quotes]. It's usual to use an f string now days; **worksheet.print_area = f"A1:F{max_rows}"**. The variable is included in the string surrounded by curly brackets, [note the 'f' at the start if the string]. You don't need to cast max_rows to string

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much! I finally figured out it was a String issue yesterday and tried lots of different things but never figured it out. This worked like a charm. I just need to learn more about how all of this stuff works. Thanks again!